# To dimension an incoming variable or to not

Tags: vb.net

What is the difference between doing this:

```
Public Sub MySub(ByVal MyString as String)
    Dim TheString as String = MyString
    myFunction(TheString)
    'Some more code...
End Sub
```

Compared to this:

```
Public Sub MySub(ByVal MyString as String)
    MyFunction(MyString)
    'Some more code
End Sub
```

That is, is there a good reason to dimension a variable in a function/sub again before using it from the argument line? Or does it not matter?

Hope this makes sense, I wasn't sure how to word this question.

Comment: as written, the first block is pointless because the strings are equal.  In cases where myFunction needs to work on a modified form of the one passed, its fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a value based `Type` (e.g: `string` or `integer`, `double` etc.), unless it's passed using the reference (`ByRef`) instead of the value (`ByVal`), you shouldn't need to worry about storing it in another variable (unless you wish to have 2 copies)

Comment: @MicroR It depends on the `Type`, as some things like `Image` and custom `Objects` act differently. These normally pass their reference (`ByRef`) regardless of the fact that they are meant to be passed as a value (`ByVal`)

Answer (score 1):

If the function required a modified string, so you were changing it to fit that, the first code block would make some sense.

However--since it's equal, the only case I can think of you needing the first block of code is if you're needing to keep myString the same within that sub...but I would think if you were doing something like that, most of the time you would just have a totally different sub.

Because you used ByVal-- once you exit that sub, myString will once again be whatever it was initially set to before you entered the sub, because the mystring you're working with inside of the sub is just a copy of the value.

In contrast, if you used ByRef the changes made to the variable **would** be taken back to the main code and actually change the value of mystring.

You can read about the difference between ByVal and ByRef here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/07b9d3b9-5658-49ed-9218-005564e8209e/what-is-the-difference-between-byval-and-byref

You can take all these concepts and play with how it works in a simple *console program* to further your understanding. That's what I did, here's some of the code I toyed with to double check what I was saying. Try changing where ByVal & ByRef is used, and maybe printing to the screen after you make a change to see what sticks and what doesn't.

```
Sub Main()
        Dim someString As String = "This is some string."


        MySub(someString)
        Console.WriteLine(someString)

        MyOtherSub(someString)
        Console.WriteLine(someString)


        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Public Sub MySub(ByVal myString As String)
        Dim theString As String = myString
        MyFunction(theString)
        ' First line printed in console.
        Console.WriteLine(theString)
        theString = "Hello."
        Console.WriteLine(theString)
        Console.WriteLine(myString)
        myString = "I'm mystring."
        Console.WriteLine(myString)
    End Sub



    Public Sub MyOtherSub(ByVal MyString As String)
        MyFunction(MyString)
    End Sub

    Public Function MyFunction(ByRef mystring As String)
        mystring += "myFunction is acting on this string."

    End Function
```